# Start learning synthesis

Tags: synthesis

I'm new to electronic music and this community (not to "regular" music nor SE). I'm thinking about getting a Bass Station II because I've been playing with NI Massive and some other VST's but I prefer something "real". Do you know any course or somewhere I could learn about OSC, Filters, ADSR. Thanks

Comment: This question (and answer(s)) might be more appropriate at Music.SE, so much so I think it might be a duplicat there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many great resources. At the risk of providing a link(s) only answer:

[Sound on Sound's *Synth Secrets* series](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/allsynthsecrets.htm)

[Moog Music's *Fundamentals of Synthesizer Programming* videos](http://www.moogmusic.com/legacy/fundamentals-synthesizer-programming)

[Keyboard Magazine's How-To section](http://www.keyboardmag.com/content/how-to/1255)

[*Welsh's Synthesizer Cookbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ERHA4S) (Amazon.com link - only available in print)

[A decent web search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=synth%20programming) will turn up many, many more options

Comment: I'd like to add a book;  **Martin Russ's _'Sound Synthesis and Sampling'_** as it was required reading in university, and taught me a lot.